# What to use to avoid overcompensating in a multi-objective model in Cplex Java?

Tags: java, cplex

I'm setting up a multi-objective optimization model with Cplex in my Java application. However, when it solves the model, it overcompensates one variable while the rest are 0. What can I use to have a more distributed solution?

```java
 int[] x = {49,43,43,44,48,49,51,54,51,52,57,59};
 double[] y = {10, 12, 13.2, 22.7, 17.1, 16.5, 14.87, 12, 16.5, 14.8, 12, 11.5};
int[] z = {59, 59, 57, 57, 53, 53, 52, 51, 51, 50, 50, 50};
int totalVacations = 73;

        try {
            IloCplex model = new IloCplex();
            int size = 12;
            IloNumVarType varType = IloNumVarType.Int;
            double[] lb = new double[size];
            double[] ub = new double[size];
            IloNumVarType[] varTypes = new IloNumVarType[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < lb.length ; i++) {
                lb[i] = 0.0;
                ub[i] = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                varTypes[i] = varType;
            }
            IloNumVar[] varUsed = model.numVarArray(size, lb, ub, varTypes);
            for (int i = 0; i < varUsed.length; i++) {
                model.add(varUsed[i]);
            }
            IloNumExpr[] objArray = new IloNumExpr[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
                IloObjective next = model.maximize();
                IloNumExpr exprVar = varUsed[i];
                double setValue = z[i] - x[i] - y[i];
                next.setExpr(model.diff(setValue, exprVar));
                next.setSense(IloObjectiveSense.Maximize);
                objArray[i] = next.getExpr();
            }

            model.add(model.maximize(model.staticLex(objArray)));
            model.addEq(totalVacations, model.sum(varUsed), "c1");
            if (model.solve()) {
                double[] results = model.getValues(varUsed);
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(results[i]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(model.toString());
            model.end();
        } catch (IloException e) {
            System.err.println("Concert exception caught: " + e);
        }
```

The values are 
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
73.0

When I want it to be more distributed (not evenly though). Any recommendations on what to do in that case?

Comment: Like Alex said in his answer, there is no incentive to pick any of the other variables. You will have to change the objective coefficients (the "weights" of the variables) ot make other variables more preferrable. Note that starting with version 12.9, CPLEX has direct support for multi-objective optimization. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/multiobj/partMultiobj_title_synopsis.html and also the `Diet.java` example shipped with CPLEX.

Answer (score 2):

Let me use OPL in order to show you what to do:

You wrote the Java equivalent of

```
int totalVacation=73;
range r=1..12;

int  x[r] = [49,43,43,44,48,49,51,54,51,52,57,59];
float y[r] = [10, 12, 13.2, 22.7, 17.1, 16.5, 14.87, 12, 16.5, 14.8, 12, 11.5];
float z[r] = [59, 59, 57, 57, 53, 53, 52, 51, 51, 50, 50, 50];

dvar int varUsed[r] in 0..totalVacation;

maximize sum(i in r) (z[i] - x[i] - y[i]-varUsed[i]);

subject to
{
c1:sum(i in r) varUsed[i]==totalVacation;
}
```

which gives

```
varUsed = [73 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
```

because there is nothing in the objective about fairness.

But if you change the objective from

```
maximize sum(i in r) (z[i] - x[i] - y[i]-varUsed[i]);
```

to

```
maximize staticLex(sum(i in r) (z[i] - x[i] - y[i]-varUsed[i]),
        -max(j in r) varUsed[j]+min(j in r) varUsed[j]);
```

Then you add a second lexicographic objective to maximize fairness and then you will get

```
varUsed = [7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6];
```